# Hensel's lemma, Bezout's identity, and the integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, prime-numbers, factorization, factorization-theory

Factorization in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)\mathbb{Z}[x]\cong \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is well known.  For instance, $5$ and $13$ (and any prime $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$) are no longer prime.

The factorization of $5$ lifts to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/((x^2+1)^2)\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but it isn't a simple consequence of Hensel's lemma.  The trouble with using Hensel's lemma is that it requires a form of Bezout's identity, which does not generally hold over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Instead, for any two coprime polynomials $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, all we know in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is that there exists some polynomials $c,d\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $ac+bd\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$.

For example, $1+2x$ and $1-2x$ are relatively prime, but the "smallest" positive integer that is a linear combination is
$$
(1+2x)+(1-2x) = 2.
$$
Note that $5=(1+2x)(1-2x) + 4(1+x^2)$, and the coefficient on $(1+x^2)$ is divisible by $2$.  This lucky coincidence is what allows us to lift the factorization of $5$.

The factorization of $13$ as $(2+3x)(2-3x)\pmod{(1+x^2)}$ also lifts (as pointed out in the comments below by Johan).  Here, the smallest positive integer $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-linear combination of $2+3x$ and $2-3x$ is $4$, and that's not enough.  But the smallest $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-linear combination of $2+3x$, $2-3x$, and $1+x^2$ is $1$, which is enough.

**Question**:  Given a monic irreducible polynomial $q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, of degree at least $2$, and an integer $n\geq 2$, is there some integer prime $p$ that factors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/q(x)^n\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

This question arose thinking about [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406475/existence-of-a-finite-extension-of-%E2%84%A4-providing-a-finite-extension-of-the-primes).

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$?

Comment: @LucGuyot Sorry, I thought it was obvious that I intended $\deg(q)\geq 2$.  I've now made that clear.  The point of my question is whether at least one prime factorization **lifts**.  There are no (nontrivial) factorizations when $q$ is linear.  So of course there can't be any such factorizations if we go from working mod $q$ to mod $q^2$.

Comment: What's the difference between $13=(3+2x)(3-2x)+4(1+x^2)$ and $5=(1+2x)(1-2x)+4(1+x^2)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The difference is that the smallest positive integer that is a $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-linear combination of $3+2x$ and $3-2x$ is $6$, which doesn't divide $4$.

Comment: $13 = (2 + 3*x + (1 + 3*x)*(1 + x^2)))*(2 - 3*x - (1 + x^2)) \bmod (1 + x^2)^2$ according to  my pari/gp

Comment: You are missing a quotient symbol / in the first sentence of the second paragraph.

Comment: @Johan You are correct!  Apparently, I made an error.  I'll correct my post soon.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks!  Fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $\mathcal{O} = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(q(x))$ is the ring of integers of a number field $K$. One can search for a prime $p$ which is not inert in $\mathcal{O}$ and such that there is a principal prime ideal above $p$. I think such primes exist because the density of principal prime ideals is $1/h$, where $h$ is the class number of $\mathcal{O}$ (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375142/how-many-non-principal-prime-ideals-does-a-number-field-contain)), and because the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}$ lying above an inert prime have density 0 (because their norm is $p^{[K:\mathbb{Q}]}$).

Write $p \mathcal{O} = \mathcal{P} \cdot I$ where $\mathcal{P} = (a)$ is a prime ideal, $I = (b) \neq \mathcal{O}$ is coprime to $\mathcal{P}$ and $p=ab$ in $\mathcal{O}$. Then you will have $p=a(x)b(x)+q(x)r(x)$ for some $a(x), b(x), r(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and Hensel's lemma will work because $\langle a(x), b(x), q(x) \rangle = \mathbb{Z}[x]$. It will give a factorisation of $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q(x))^n$ for every $n \geq 2$.

Comment: In general, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q)$ won't be the full ring of integers, but that can probably be overcome.  However, I still have a question.  After Johan's comment, I also was thinking about showing $\langle a,b,q\rangle = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  How do you show that equality in general?

Comment: @PaceNielsen Here, this is because $\mathcal{P}+I=\mathcal{O}$. More generally, in a Dedekind domain $R$, you just need two coprime ideals $I,J$, this implies $I+J=R$.

Comment: Unfortunately, generally we don't have a Dedekind domain.  (For instance, try $q(x)=x^2-8$.)

Comment: Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(q)$. Let $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ be the full ring of integers, and let $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q)$, which is an order in the ring of integers. Let $m=[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathcal{O}]$. Let $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ be prime, and relatively prime to $m$, and not ramified in $\mathcal{O}_K$.  These conditions only disqualify finitely many primes.  Assume that $p=ab$ for some (nonunits) $a,b\in \mathcal{O}$.  (They remain nonunits in $\mathcal{O}_K$, since any algebraic integer unit $u$ has norm $\pm 1$, and hence has an inverse that is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of powers of $u$.)

Comment: Now $a\mathcal{O}_K$ and $b\mathcal{O}_K$ are relatively prime, since $p$ is not ramified.  Thus, $ax+by=1$ for some $x,y\in \mathcal{O}_K$.  Hence $a(mx)+b(my)=m$ with $mx,my\in \mathcal{O}$.  Thus, $\langle a,b,q\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}\supseteq \langle p,m\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}=\langle 1\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}[x]}=\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  So, the only question left is whether there are primes that have nontrivial factorizations in $\mathcal{O}$ (rather than just in $\mathcal{O}_K$).  I expect that is true, and well known to experts.

Comment: John Voight says: Yes, this is a consequence of the Chebotarev density theorem, which implies that the trivial class in (the finite abelian group) Pic(R) is represented by infinitely many primes of degree 1: i.e., there are infinitely many principal primes pp = pi.R in Pic(R).  Taking norms, we get
  Nm(pp) = p = +/- Nm(pi).
We have
  Nm(pi) = pi.mu with mu in R
from Galois theory...  Adjusting signs we get
  p = pi.mu with pi, mu in R.
We can't have pi a unit (its norm is p), and taking norms,
  Nm(p) = p^d = p.Nm(mu)
so as long as d = deg q(x) > 1, we have that mu is also not a unit.